# jQuery resizable plugin

Tags: jquery

Can I specify width and height via options or something rather than dragging the handlers? (The matter is I want to use alsoResize option.)

Answer (score 2):

Being appropriately designed, the plugin doesn't mess with, or gets messed up by, core jQuery/css behaviour.

You can do any of the below:

```
$("#resizable").width(100);
$("#resizable").height(100);
$("#resizable").css({width: 100, height: 100});
```